# How can I break this multithreaded python script into "chunks"?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm processing 100k domain names into a CSV based on results taken from Siteadvisor using urllib (not the best method, I know). However, my current script creates too many threads and Python runs into errors. Is there a way I can "chunk" this script to do X number of domains at a time (say, 10-20) to prevent these errors? Thanks in advance.

```
import threading
import urllib

class Resolver(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, address, result_dict):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.address = address
        self.result_dict = result_dict

    def run(self):
        try:
            content = urllib.urlopen("http://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/" + self.address).read(12000)
            search1 = content.find("didn't find any significant problems.")
            search2 = content.find('yellow')
            search3 = content.find('web reputation analysis found potential security')
            search4 = content.find("don't have the results yet.")

            if search1 != -1:
                result = "safe"
            elif search2 != -1:
                result = "caution"
            elif search3 != -1:
                result = "warning"
            elif search4 != -1:
                result = "unknown"
            else:
                result = ""

            self.result_dict[self.address] = result

        except:
            pass


def main():
    infile = open("domainslist", "r")
    intext = infile.readlines()
    threads = []
    results = {}
    for address in [address.strip() for address in intext if address.strip()]:
        resolver_thread = Resolver(address, results)
        threads.append(resolver_thread)
        resolver_thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    outfile = open('final.csv', 'w')
    outfile.write("\n".join("%s,%s" % (address, ip) for address, ip in results.iteritems()))
    outfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Edit**: new version, based on andyortlieb's suggestions.

```
import threading
import urllib
import time

class Resolver(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, address, result_dict, threads):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.address = address
        self.result_dict = result_dict
        self.threads = threads
    def run(self):
        try:
            content = urllib.urlopen("http://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/" + self.address).read(12000)
            search1 = content.find("didn't find any significant problems.")
            search2 = content.find('yellow')
            search3 = content.find('web reputation analysis found potential security')
            search4 = content.find("don't have the results yet.")

            if search1 != -1:
                result = "safe"
            elif search2 != -1:
                result = "caution"
            elif search3 != -1:
                result = "warning"
            elif search4 != -1:
                result = "unknown"
            else:
                result = ""

            self.result_dict[self.address] = result

            outfile = open('final.csv', 'a')
            outfile.write(self.address + "," + result + "\n")
            outfile.close()
            print self.address + result

            threads.remove(self)
        except:
            pass


def main():
    infile = open("domainslist", "r")
    intext = infile.readlines()
    threads = []
    results = {}

    for address in [address.strip() for address in intext if address.strip()]:
        loop=True
        while loop:
            if len(threads) < 20:
                resolver_thread = Resolver(address, results, threads)
                threads.append(resolver_thread)
                resolver_thread.start()
                loop=False
            else:
                time.sleep(.25)


    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

#    removed so I can track the progress of the script
#    outfile = open('final.csv', 'w')
#    outfile.write("\n".join("%s,%s" % (address, ip) for address, ip in results.iteritems()))
#    outfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be kind of rigid, but you could pass threads to Resolver, so that when Resolver.run is completed, it can call threads.remove(self)

Then you can nest some conditions so that threads are only created if there is room for them, and if there isn't room, they wait until there is.

```
for address in [address.strip() for address in intext if address.strip()]:
        loop=True
        while loop:
            if len(threads)<20:
                resolver_thread = Resolver(address, results, threads)
                threads.append(resolver_thread)
                resolver_thread.start()
                loop=False
            else: 
                time.sleep(.25)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I've implemented your changes. However, the script only gets as far as 20 domains. I've put my script above. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: I believe all you need is to change threads.remove(self) to self.threads.remove(self)

Comment: Facepalm. Didn't see that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're going to want to get rid of that try: block with no exceptions to troubleshoot why 50% of the time the script doesn't terminate (I'm willing to bet it's because exceptions aren't being properly handled).  It could be an exception either from urllib or perhaps from racing to that csv file.  So I have a couple more suggestions: Actually do something on that except block... AT LEAST remove self from self.threads again.    Another suggestion: rather than writing to the csv from the thread, write to a common dictionary, and write the csv from main() after all the threads have ended.

Comment: Sorry, just one last remark, circumventing the try: block altogether, i had no problems with the code hanging. Don't know why, but thought I would share FYI.  Thank you for the acceptance.

Answer (score 2):

Your existing code will work beautifully - just modify your `__init__` method inside `Resolver` to take in an additional list of addresses instead of one at a time, so instead of having one thread for each address, you have one thread for every 10 (for example). That way you won't overload the threading.

You'll obviously have to slightly modify `run` as well so it loops through the array of addresses instead of the one `self.address`.

I can work up a quick example if you'd like, but from the quality of your code I feel as though you'll be able to handle it quite easily.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT** Example below as requested. Note that you'll have to modify main to send your `Resolver` instance lists of addresses instead of a single address - I couldn't handle this for you without knowing more about the format of your file and how the addresses are stored. Note - you could do the `run` method with a helper function, but i thought this might be more understandable as an example

```
class Resolver(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, addresses, result_dict):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.addresses = addresses  # Now takes in a list of multiple addresses
        self.result_dict = result_dict

    def run(self):
        for address in self.addresses: # do your existing code for every address in the list
            try:
                content = urllib.urlopen("http://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/" + address).read(12000)
                search1 = content.find("didn't find any significant problems.")
                search2 = content.find('yellow')
                search3 = content.find('web reputation analysis found potential security')
                search4 = content.find("don't have the results yet.")

                if search1 != -1:
                    result = "safe"
                elif search2 != -1:
                    result = "caution"
                elif search3 != -1:
                    result = "warning"
                elif search4 != -1:
                    result = "unknown"
                else:
                    result = ""

                self.result_dict[address] = result
            except:
                pass
```

Comment: Can you post an example, please?

Comment: I just edited my answer with a quick example - you'll have to edit your `run` method to pass in lists of addresses instead of a single address, but I left that to you as I don't know how your input file, etc. is formatted and I don't want to pass along broken code. As you can see it's a minor change.

Comment: So in this case, would you be dividing your address list by the number of threads you're allowing to be created, and passing those sections of the address list to Resolver?  If so, then you may want to move all the strip() stuff out of main and into Resolver.

Comment: Exactly! I just wanted to avoid confusing the issue of getting fewer threads running with the issue of how exactly to put the lists of addresses into the Resolver. It would probably be best, as you suggested, to pass blocks of `n` lines at a time, and then pre-process those lines in the Resolver `__init__` method before `run` deals with them.